# OpenCV(4.5.2)/tmp/pip-req-build-eirhwqtr/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, django-views, django-forms, python-tesseract

I want to extract text from images that I had uploaded using django forms.
This is my view.py

```py
from django.http.response import HttpResponseBadRequest
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm, UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UploadFileForm, EditFileName
from .models import Image
import cv2
import pytesseract


@login_required
def home(request):
    context = {}

    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.user)
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print(request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.user
            image_text = request.FILES["image"].name
            image = form.cleaned_data.get("image")
            image_path = "../media/storage" + str(image)
            image_clone = cv2.imread(image_path)
            image_clone = cv2.cvtColor(image_clone, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            image_clone = cv2.threshold(
                image_clone, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
            image_clone = cv2.medianBlur(image_clone, 5)
            OCRtext = pytesseract.image_to_string(image_clone)
            obj = Image.objects.create(
                username=username,
                image_text=image_text,
                image=image,
                OCRtext=OCRtext
            )
            obj.save()
            print(obj)
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
        form2 = EditFileName()
        context['form2'] = form2
    context['form'] = form
    context['data'] = Image.objects.all()
    print(context)
    return render(request, "registration/success.html", context)


def edit(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        print('--------------')
        form2 = EditFileName(request.POST)
        if form2.is_valid():
            username = request.user
            image_text = form2.cleaned_data.get("image_text")
            obj = Image.objects.filter(id=request.POST['image_id']).update(
                image_text=image_text
            )

            print('obj in form2', obj)
    form2 = EditFileName()
    context['form2'] = form2
    form = UploadFileForm()
    context['form'] = form
    context['data'] = Image.objects.all()
    print(context)
    return redirect('/home/')


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form': form})
```

I get this error -

```
File "/media/samarpan/DATA1/task/users/views.py", line 26, in home
    image_clone = cv2.cvtColor(image_clone, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) /tmp/pip-req-build-eirhwqtr/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'
```

The image uploaded by django form is being stored in `request.FILES`. I need to get the image path.

I understand that this error is because the image source isn't right in `image_path = "../media/storage" + str(image)` - What is the fix?

repo link - https://github.com/smrpn/task/

Comment: Print out `image_path`. Is it what you expect? Does it give the correct path to your desired image?

Answer (score 0):

I were also getting the similar type of error

"error: OpenCV(4.5.2) /tmp/pip-req-build-eirhwqtr/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'"

But its because I mistakenly give wrong path of images.